# How to understand graphviz dot edge and node behavior?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Coming from this graph:

```
digraph G {

a0 -> a1 -> a2;
x0 -> x1;
b0 -> b1 -> b2;

}
```

which is giving this graphical representation:

```
a 0    x 0    b 0
 |      |      |
a 1    x 1    b 1
 |             |
a 2           b 2
```

I'd like to connect a2 to x1 and x1 to b2.

So I tried:

```
digraph G {

a0 -> a1 -> a2;
x0 -> x1;
b0 -> b1 -> b2;

a2 -> x1 [constraint=false];
x1 -> b2 [constraint=false];

}
```

My expectation would be this:

```
a 0    x 0    b 0
 |      |      |
a 1    x 1    b 1
 |  /       \  |
a 2           b 2
```

But unfortunately it is rendered like this and I have no clue why.

```
a 0    b 0    x 0
 |      |      |
 |      |      |
 |      |      |
a 1    b 1    x 1
 |      | _ / / 
 |      +    / 
 |  _/   |  /  
a 2    b 2
```

How can I gain a better understanding of why is that and help me to keep x0 -> x1 in the middle of the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `{rank=same; a0 -> x0 -> b0 [style=invis];}` to your graph gives the desired result - this forces the top nodes to be in a specific order, but hides the edges added to do this.  I have absolutely no idea why this should be necessary, however.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps for this case. But adding one level and it't driving me nuts again.
Please try

    digraph G {
     a0 -> a1 ->  a2 -> a3;
     b0 -> b1;
     c0 -> c1 ->  c2 ->c3;
     a3 -> b1 [constraint=false]
     b1 -> c3 [constraint=false]
     {rank=same a0 -> b0 -> c0 [style=invis];}
    }

Comment: Wow, that's got to be a bug...  Adding `splines="line";` seems to work in this case; "ortho" or "curved" may be needed in other layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Using constraint=false seems to lead to 'special' results.

The following graph gives the desired result.
Looks like structuring the nodes in it's natural ranking and using dir=back works much better.

```
digraph G {
    a0 -> a1 -> a2;
    x0 -> x1;
    b0 -> b1 -> b2;
    x1 -> a2 [dir=back];
    x1 -> b2;
}
```